# Three (almost?) identical functions return different results

Tags: javascript

I am doing simple challenges on LeetCode trying to make the fastest solution possible. The challenge I did is:

> Given the array `nums`, for each `nums[i]` find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than it. That is, for each `nums[i]` you have to count the number of valid `j's` such that `j != i` **and** `nums[j] < nums[i]`

The following code shows 3 different outputs in console:

```
const smallerNumbersThanCurrent = (nums) => {
  console.log(nums.map((num) => [...nums].sort((a, b) => a - b).indexOf(num)));
  console.log(nums.map((num) => nums.sort((a, b) => a - b).indexOf(num)));
  return nums.map((num) => [...nums].sort((a, b) => a - b).indexOf(num));
};

console.log(smallerNumbersThanCurrent([2, 5, 1, 3]));
```

The output is:

```
[ 1, 3, 0, 2 ]
[ 1, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

If there is no console.log, the output of the function is always correct, but now only the first output is correct. Why does it behave this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts the elements of an array **in place** and returns the sorted array.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why absolutely identical functions in the first console.log and return return different results. Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Your second `console.log(nums.map((num) => nums.sort((a, b) => a - b).indexOf(num)));` mutate(sort) `nums` array, because of which `return nums.` work with sorted array.